Some clarifications on the derivation of adiabatic process equation conducted on uninsulated container very fast
Assume a situation where an adiabatic process is carried out in an uninsulated container. So, for the process to be adiabatic, it should be carried out very fast.
Also, in the derivation of the adiabatic process equation $PV^{\gamma} = constant$, we  do the following

But for the substitution of $2$ in $1$, we should have both external pressure and pressure due to gas to be equal. But since the process is taking very fast, there is no equilibrium and no guarantee for the pressures to be equal. Then how can we do the substitution, or is $PV^{\gamma}$ valid for only reversible adiabatic processes? Or can we create equilibrium by carrying the process in a pace such that there is no time for conduction, but there is enough time for equilibrium to be attained?


But for the substitution of 2 in 1, we should have both external
pressure and pressure due to gas to be equal.

Since the process is carried out very fast, the external and internal pressures are only equal at the boundary between the system and surroundings. Within the gas, however, gas pressure (and temperature) varies internally. Thus you cannot apply the ideal gas law (which only applies to gas equilibrium states) in your derivation.
Bottom line, $PV^{\gamma}$=constant only applies for a reversible adiabatic process.
Hope this helps.

Thanks Bob D, I was also suspecting it is not valid.

Also, could anyone please tell me why my question is marked as off topic?

@SemiballisticS off hand it’s not clear to me why it’s off topic. Something to do with the type of link you used.
